# General WMS connection problem in QGIS 3.10.9 at my working place

Tags: qgis, wms

At my working place I am not able to connect any wms. The same services work at home with the same laptop and version of QGIS. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

The error message when connecting:

```
Properties query failed:
Properties query failed: Host www.lfu.bayern.de could not be found
```

Answer (score 2):

You should activate the Proxy for webaccess: settings->options->Network->use Proxy for webaccess

[image]